# Is there need for an overall 3D stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about 3d in a different program than blender but there is no stack exchange for just 3d , there is programming and graphics.

Can I ask questions about 3ds max here anyway?

The question is about decimating my model with too many polys in 3ds max.

Comment: First, ask this on meta. Second, no. Third, ask about 3DS Max on Graphics SE.

Comment: @ShadyPuck 3D stuff is now [officially off-topic on Graphics SE](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2548/26236).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>There is currently a [proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics) for a general 3D non-programming stack exchange, including questions about 3DS Max.  As of this writing it is in the "commitment" phase, so not usable yet.  It needs more committers before it can move into beta.</strike>

Update: The above proposal expired.  After spending a year in a particular stage, Area 51 automatically closes a proposal, but they do so with a nice message explaining that some of the most successful Stack Exchange sites have come from stalled proposals that were closed and restarted from scratch.

So, follow the new [3D Modeling and Animation proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109293/3d-modeling-and-animation), and add some good sample questions to it, or just vote on the questions there.  The proposed site has potential benefits even users of this site, since it will cover questions about getting Blender assets in and out of other tools like Substance Painter, Marmoset Toolbag, and other rendering packages and engines.  What happens if an artist exports a model from Blender into Unity 3D and it doesn't look right, and Unity settings need to be tweaked?  You shouldn't ask here about Unity settings.  That's why the new proposal is needed.

Comment: I'd like to add that [this has been tried once before without success](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics), so if this is an SE site you'd like to see in action, please do consider committing and participating in the private beta. They need everyone they can get

Comment: With the upsurge in these creative tools from Quixel, Allegorithmic etc, a bit feasible but again one of my main arguments was that people who use these things are usually trained professionals. Same went for the last proposal that centered around Max, ZBrush etc, you have to shell out serious dollars to get access to these tools as opposed to us (Blender) being free. Also arguable seeing how Graphics.SE runs on PS and AI but that is a different niche and this will probably fail again for the same reason(s), lack of traffic ie.

Comment: @iKlsR Yep, points well taken.  Still, a lot of engines are embracing this "free for indie devs" strategy lately, and even the lower-tier 3D pros don't always pay for top-tier tech support.  Several packages have demo periods and educational bundles, etc.  Plus, there are a lot of interoperability questions between tools (including Blender) that experts in a single tool may not be familiar with.  So I think there is a community waiting to happen.

Comment: So, the 3d graphics proposal died.. That's big news and not good one.

Comment: @MrZak bad news indeed!  But it's part of the Area 51 mechanism, after spending a year in a particular stage, a proposal must be closed and restarted from scratch.  For some sites, such as Mathematica, the rebooted proposal is far more successful than the original.  So don't abandon hope, [follow the new proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109293/3d-modeling-and-animation) and add some good sample questions.